# Laravel Blank white page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a problem with my get route in a group. here is my code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'commodities'], function(){
    Route::get('commodities', [
        'as' => 'showCommodities', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@showAll'
    ]);

    Route::get('{id}', [
        'as' => 'showCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@show'
    ]);

    Route::get('add', [
        'as' => 'addCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@create'
    ]);

    Route::post('update', [
        'as' => 'updateCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@update'
    ]);

    Route::post('destroy', [
        'as' => 'destroyCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@destroy'
    ]);

    Route::post('add', [
        'as' => 'storeCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@store'
    ]);
});
```

I pasted the `CommodityController` code here http://pastebin.com/bWrdVhsv

Everything works except the GET route `commodites/add`. I always get a white page. My debug is set to `TRUE` and I have the correct blade for it.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you show us your `CommodityController`?

Comment: @Adrenaxus, updated my post

Comment: Are you sure you have a file named `add.blade.php` in `views/pages/admin/commodity`?

Comment: I have add.blade.php @Adrenaxus

Comment: is your view file name is add.blade.php or create.blade.php? If it is add.blade.php then please show us that code also

Comment: If you put some rubbish into `add.blade.php`, you still get a white page or an error?

Comment: @ramsai, even if I return "any text" in the public function create, it still shows a white page

Comment: @Adrenaxus, i still get white page even if i put something like hello

Comment: so it is not going to the view as you mentioned in the controller. So please check once in log files whether it is throwing any error?

Comment: The problem is the order of your routes.

Comment: @Jeemusu, I suspect that also. What's the proper order?

Comment: Added an answer. Your `{id}` route is catching all the urls with a get request, so the `add` route is being ignored.

Comment: Well then I suspect it has something to do with your last route which defines add on POST... Do you maybe call add as a post? Try writing some rubbish in your `store.blade.php` and see if that one gets called instead of the `add.blade.php` view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the order of your routes.

Move the `add` route above your catch all `{id}` route.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'commodities'], function(){
    Route::get('commodities', [
        'as' => 'showCommodities', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@showAll'
    ]);

    Route::get('add', [
        'as' => 'addCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@create'
    ]);

    Route::get('{id}', [
        'as' => 'showCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@show'
    ]);

    Route::post('update', [
        'as' => 'updateCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@update'
    ]);

    Route::post('destroy', [
        'as' => 'destroyCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@destroy'
    ]);

    Route::post('add', [
        'as' => 'storeCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@store'
    ]);
});
```

Laravel will go through your routes.php file top to bottom. The below route is essentially a catch all.

```
Route::get('{id}', [
        'as' => 'showCommodity', 'uses' => 'CommodityController@show'
]);
```

This means it will catch all GET requests to urls that match the pattern:

`/commodities/some-kind-of-string`.

As the `/commodities/add` uri matches the above pattern it will use that route because it appears first in the routes file.

Comment: Good catch! I overlooked that one.

Comment: BTW, how does the order affect this one?

Comment: I will add some more details, but basically laravel goes though the routes in order. So it gets to the `{id}` route first, which is catching all the get routes to urls that are similar to `/commodities/whatever-goes-here`

Comment: @FewFlyBy after updating your views once check all the views are loading as per your routes

Comment: WIll wait for your detailed info, thank you @Jeemusu