# Laravel blank white screen and no errors after modification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My laravel site working well. But after modification i faced with a blank white screen and no logs.

If I run below command :

```
php -cli artisan clear-compiled
```

I have this error :

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
> 'Class log does not exist' in
> /data/devPhp/workspace/adhesion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734
>     Stack trace:
>     #0 /data/devPhp/workspace/adhesion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(734):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
>     #1 /data/devPhp/workspace/adhesion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
>     #2 /data/devPhp/workspace/adhesion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
>     #3 /data/devPhp/workspace/adhesion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(849):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Psr\Log\LoggerI...')
>     #4 /data/devPhp/workspace/adhesion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(804):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
>     #5 /data/devPhp/workspac in /data/devPhp/workspace/adhesion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 734
```

Comment: try to run 'composer dump-autoload'

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due to space in values of .env file :

wrong example :

```
MAIL_USERNAME = a@gmail.com
TOWN=a town
```

good example :

```
MAIL_USERNAME=a@gmail.com
TOWN='a town'
```

But other case could cause white blank screen such right in file and folder :

[Laravel blank white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen)

[Laravel 5.3 blank white screen no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234890/laravel-5-3-blank-white-screen-no-errors)

[Laravel Blank white page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230766/laravel-blank-white-page)

Comment: If I could vote this +1000 I would. Saved me big time today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your namespaces are correct when referencing a class.

Probably have something like new Log(); when it should be new Acme\Log(); replacing Acme whatever your namespace is. Maybe Log() is log() by mistake.

**Or try running**

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are still errors and you don't have access on SSH, maybe try to delete the cache files:

- Bootstrap: *services.php, settings.php* -> Delete
- *Storage/Framework/Cache* -> Delete all files
- *Storage/Framework/session* -> Delete all files
- *Storage/Framework/views* -> Delete all files

And refresh the site. Good luck :)